# Window.getSelection changes after being set to another object (Reference issue?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, sweetalert, getselection

Hello fellow Stackers,

I seem to have a problem that my window.getselection object changes after I set it to another object. Here is an example:

```
document.getElementById('sendContent').focus(); //sendcontent is a contenteditable Div
current_position = window.getSelection(); //gets the selection inside sendContent  
console.log(current_position); //at the console.log, the window.getSelection is the right one
pasteHtmlAtCaret(true); //here a sweetalert shows
```

After this, a SweetAlert pops up where the user has to enter a URL, which is then posted to the current_position .
But it seems that current_position changes in runtime, here's what happens:

**At the first console.log:**

- current_position = Selection {anchorNode: text, anchorOffset: 27, focusNode: text,.... etc.

**But after the sweetalert shows, current_position changes to:**

- current_position = Selection {anchorNode: div.swal2-modal.swal2-show, anchorOffset: 9, focusNode: div.swal2-modal.swal2-show,.... etc.

---

I tried freezing/deepfreezing current_position after I first set it but that won't work, it still changes in runtime.

It maybe has something to do with that current_position has a reference to the window.getselection property and so it changes every time the selection of the window changes. But my question is. Can I work around this?

I need the selection before the SweetAlert pops up.

EDIT 1:

This is what I want to do with the selection:

```
var sel, range;
                        if (window.getSelection) {
                            // IE9 and non-IE
                            sel = current_position;
                            if (sel.getRangeAt && sel.rangeCount) {
                                range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
                                range.deleteContents();

                                // Range.createContextualFragment() would be useful here but is
                                // non-standard and not supported in all browsers (IE9, for one)
                                var el = document.createElement("div");
                                el.innerHTML = html;
                                var frag = document.createDocumentFragment(), node, lastNode;
                                while ((node = el.firstChild)) {
                                    lastNode = frag.appendChild(node);
                                }
                                range.insertNode(frag);

                                // Preserve the selection
                                if (lastNode) {
                                    range = range.cloneRange();
                                    range.setStartAfter(lastNode);
                                    range.collapse(true);
                                    sel.removeAllRanges();
                                    sel.addRange(range);
                                }
                            }
```

Comment: It appears the object returned by window.getSelection has circular references, something I missed in my answer. Do you need to save the entire object? Or just specific properties of it?

Comment: I need enough objects to do: See updated answer

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this? I have the same issue, but it only seems to happen on Windows. I make a selection, then I pop open a dialog to change the selection color, and the selection changes. Mine is chrome only as I am building an app in electron.

Comment: @NinjaBeetle I did manage to make a workaround for it. Don't have access to the code anymore unfortunately. It was mostly just trial and error...
If I find the answer again I'll tell you.